# Mapping priority of a fortify issue to severity in sonar

Tags: sonarqube, fortify

I am currently using sonar 4.5.7 and was able to install "sonar-fortify-plugin-2.0" on it.Thereafter I generated an fpr file for a corresponding git repo through Fortify (16.11) and uploaded it in on my sonar test instance.

I understand there are some rules hidden in workbench by default based on below condition

```
if impact is not in range ![inclusive, inclusive] 2.5, 5.0
if likelihood is not in range !(exclusive, inclusive] 1.0, 5.0
```

However, for the remaining one's whether there will be correct to say that a 1-1 mapping will prevail or no ? For example :

*All critical in workbench will get mapped as blocker in sonar dashboard.*

*All high in workbench will get mapped as critical in sonar dashboard.*

Please guide.

Related links which I could find :

http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/Re-Fortify-Plugin-Is-it-possible-to-have-a-feature-to-configure-the-mapping-between-the-priority-of--td5013813.html

http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/Fortify-Plugin-Is-it-possible-to-have-a-feature-to-configure-the-mapping-between-the-priority-of-For-td5012530.html

Comment: SonarQube 4.5.7 is a very old version. The chance of a useful answer increases if you perform an update.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen.Just wanted to confirm that priority in audit workbench and severity in sonar both have different algorithm of getting deduced.They are no where related.Is this understanding correct ?